# Is it possible to have each page of a Stacked Widget specified in a separate ui file

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qstackedwidget

I am using the Stacked Widget in Qt Creator v4.14.2. Right now all of the items for each page reside in the mainwindow.ui file. I do not have a problem switching between pages.

I am wanting to put the items for each Stacked Widget page in a separate ui file for clarity and file size reasons. I understand that there is not a technically reason for this need. I have developed UIs using MVVM and would like to replicate that methodology in Qt (using Qt Creator) if at all possible.

For this project I am working on, I would prefer not do page and/or Widget creation in the C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load as many UI files as you need using [`QUiLoader`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quiloader.html).  Assuming the files are named `page-1.ui`, ... `page-10.ui` you could have something like (untested)...

```
#include <QStackedWidget>
#include <QUiLoader>
#include <QWidget>

   .
   .
   .

QStackedWidget stack;
QUiLoader loader;
for (int page_no = 1; page_no <= 10; ++page_no) {
  QFile f(QString("page-%1.ui").arg(page_no));
  if (f.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
    auto *w = loader.load(&f);
    stack.addWidget(w);
  } else {
    qWarning() << "failed to load UI file.";
  }
}
```

Comment: Pointing out the use of the QUiLoader is what I was missing. This solution works perfectly as describes. The biggest consideration with this solution is knowing the proper directory both when using the Qt Creator and running standalone.